# javascript promise unhandled reject issue

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

I'm new to javascript and have been learning about promises. However there is an issue I'm having trouble understanding:

The following code (in node.js) sets the promise status to 'rejected' where I expect the code specified in the 'catch' clause to be executed - which it is - BUT it also raises a unhandled exception *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning* despite the 'catch' clause

```
p = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    reject();  
 } );

p.then( function () {console.log("success")} );
p.catch( function () {console.log("fail")} ); // prints fail and raises exception
```

If the 'then' clause is removed it works:

```
p = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    reject();  
 } );

p.catch( function () {console.log("fail")} );  // prints fail
```

Also, if the 'catch' is chained to the 'then' it also seems to work (more confusion)

What am I not understanding?

Thank you

Comment: You can get the response of ```reject()``` by using ```.catch(err => {})``` and the response of ```resolve()``` by using ```.then(res => {})```. Chaining or before after not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be chaining your calls to the promise together, not making them as separate calls.  For example:

```
p = new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    reject();  
 } );

p.then( function () {console.log("success")} )
 .catch( function () {console.log("fail")} );
```

What you're having happen is that the first `p.then` executes, it does not handle the reject case, so it throws an exception (the unhandled error you see). The `p.catch` line also executes and you will see the "fail" output, but that won't stop the exception from the first `p.then();` call.